# Ask if you are sure you want to submit? JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, submit, alert

I currently have this.

```
 //other stuff up here - not important
    echo "<td><form action='redeem.php' method='post' id='form'><input type='hidden' name='redeem' value='1' /><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $id . "' /><input type='submit' name='Redeem' value='Redeem'></form></td>";
    } else {
    echo "<td><form action='redeem.php' method='post' id='form'><input type='hidden' name='redeem' value='0' /><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $id . "' /><input type='submit' name='Un-Redeem' value='Un-Redeem'></form></td>";
//other stuff down here - not important
```

and I want to change it so that when you press:
a) the 'Redeem' SUBMIT button it alerts you saying, "Are you sure you want to Redeem?"
b) the 'Un-Redeem' SUBMIT button it alerts you saying, "Are you sure you want to Un-Redeem?"

I have tried a few of them including the ONCLICK on the submit but none worked.. and I believe that is because I have it in an ECHO and I had to remove the (") quotation marks which stopped the function from happening.

Anyone know another way I can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
     //other stuff up here - not important
        echo "<td><form action='redeem.php' method='post' id='form'><input type='hidden' name='redeem' value='1' /><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $id . "' />
              <input type='submit' name='Redeem' value='Redeem' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Redeem?')"></form></td>";
        } else {
        echo "<td><form action='redeem.php' method='post' id='form'><input type='hidden' name='redeem' value='0' /><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $id . "' />
              <input type='submit' name='Un-Redeem' value='Un-Redeem' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Un-Redeem?')" ></form></td>";
    //other stuff down here - not important
```

**Edit:**
Added escaping character in here:

```
 //other stuff up here - not important
        echo "<td><form action='redeem.php' method='post' id='form'><input type='hidden' name='redeem' value='1' /><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $id . "' />
              <input type='submit' name='Redeem' value='Redeem' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to Redeem?')\"></form></td>";
        } else {
        echo "<td><form action='redeem.php' method='post' id='form'><input type='hidden' name='redeem' value='0' /><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $id . "' />
              <input type='submit' name='Un-Redeem' value='Un-Redeem' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to Un-Redeem?')\" ></form></td>";
    //other stuff down here - not important
```

Comment: I said in my first post that you cannot do that, you cannot have the (") quotation mark in there or else it ends the echo and winds up in an error!

Comment: got you so you just add escaping character`\`, I will fix the code

Comment: Sorry not sure if you updated it there. Do you mean instead of (") you use the (`) one?

Comment: I added `\ ` character before `"` but it did not render.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Javascript confirm function.

```
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Redeem?")) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something
}
```

You can also do this on form submit by adding the following code to your form:

```
onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Redeem?');"
```

The form will only submit if the user clicks "OK".

Comment: can add add it to the onclick attribute on the buttons: `onclick="return Confirm('question')"` -- returning false will cancel the action.

Comment: On a form submit it's much better to add it to the `onSubmit()` of the form tag. If you use `onClick` it won't be fired if the user hits enter

Comment: I told you I used onclick but it didn't work as I had to remove the (") quotation mark because it's in an echo.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript confirm function. The form won't submit if the confirm returns false.

```
<form action='redeem.php' method='post' id='form' onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to redeem')">
```

If you want to do something else if the user clicks cancel then you'll need to create a custom function:

```
function my_confirm() {
    if( confirm("Are you sure you want to redeem?") ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        // do something 
        return false;
    }
}
```

And on the form tag:

```
onSubmit="return my_confirm()"
```

Comment: Like I said above I used onclick/onsubmit and I cannot have anywhere in my code have (") and when I remove them it doesn't seem to do anything.