# javascript confirm that adds a parameter to the get/post

Tags: javascript, php, confirm

In this question:

[Ask if you are sure you want to submit? JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591937/ask-if-you-are-sure-you-want-to-submit-javascript)

The user asks if there's a way to add a "confirm y/n" to a form.. and there is, but the problem with the confirm subroutine is, if the user has javascript disabled, it is bypassed.

I'm looking to do something similar but I want to write my server-side script to expect an additional passed-parameter to indicate that the confirmation was done.. so something like y=1 passed would do it for me..  Is there a way to augment the confirm function to add a passed parameter that would work for either GET or POST inquiries and add an additional parameter if there was confirmation?

Answer (score 1):

```
<noscript>
    <input type="hidden" name="novalidate" value="true" />
</noscript>
```

Add inside your form.  Problem solved.

Comment: So I look for validate=false to invalidate instead of a value to validate?

Comment: If you have a script that's validating it then that implies the validation has a way of saying "this is valid" before sending.  Your issue is with people that don't use Javascript and avoid this validation, in which case you send this value and PHP (or whatever server-side language) checks for its existence.  If it's there, the server does the validation.

Comment: I changed the name and value to be more applicable